# Reactive streams with reactive side-effects

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2, project-reactor

I think this will be done similarly with most reactive implementations so I do not specify any specific library&language here.

What is the proper way to do reactive side effects on streams (not sure what is the proper terminology here)?

So lets say we have a stream of `Player`s. We want to transform that to a stream of only `id`s. But in addition to that, we want to do some additional reactive processing based on the ids.

Here is how one can do in not so elegant way, but what is the idiomatic way to achieve this:

```
Observable<Player> playerStream = getPlayerStream();
return playerStream
      .map(p -> p.id)
      .flatmap(id -> {
           Observable<Result> weDontCare = process(id);
           // Now the hacky part
           return weDontCare.map(__ -> id);
      })
```

Is that ok? Seems not so elegant.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#dependent-sub-flows

Comment: Btw, there exist an extension operator for RxJava that allows you to map asynchronously, which is more concise than the otherwise reasonable `flatMap` approach: https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersmapasync

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Observable<Player> playerStream = getPlayerStream();
    return playerStream
          .map(p -> p.id)
          .doOnEach(id -> { //side effect with id
            Observable<Result> weDontCare = process(id);
            weDontCare.map(__ -> id);
          })
```

Comment: First, there is no `tap` operator in RxJava. Second, `switchMap` will likely lose items for you as it keeps replacing inner observables upon new items from the playerStream, never letting the previous one's map back the `id` into the main flow.

Comment: But in example he dont need that

Comment: Read the post again. The OP wants an asynchronous call for each item but still continue the main flow with the ids from the original playerStream. Nowhere does it say the OP is fine not getting most ids at the end, which `switchMap` would loose quite happily.

Comment: That just like that

Comment: `doOnEach` can't return anything and wouldn't execute `weDontCare` anyway.

Comment: In your suggestion there is no-one subscribing to the `weDontCare` so nothing will be executed. Cold observables (as returned by the process()) do not execute unless subscribed to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know RxJava, but you also tagged project reactor, and there are two ways to do this with reactor depending on how you want the side-effects to affect your stream. If you want to wait for the side effects to happen so you can handle errors etc (my preferred way) use `delayUntil`:

```java
return getPlayerStream()
  .map(p -> p.id)
  .delayUntil(id -> process(id));
```

If you want the id to pass straight through without waiting, and instead do a fire-and-forget style side-effect, you could use `doOnNext`:

```java
return getPlayerStream()
  .map(p -> p.id)
  .doOnNext(id -> process(id).subscribe());
```